# Email Address as GET argument

Tags: get, html-email

In a URL you can do GET arguments (EX: http://www.google.com?hello=world) how would I be able to include an email address in this format? In a perfect world I would like to be able to do http://www.google.com?email=12345@gmail.com but when I try it now the @ symbol is messing it up. Would I have to convert it to a web safe text before sending the HTTP Request and then convert it back on the server? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try url encoding the @ sign, that would involve replacing the @ with %40

Comment: Most programming languages have a library function for this, e.g. `urlencode()` in PHP, `encodeURIComponent` in Javascript. Programmers should always use these when generating URLs that may contain special characters.

Comment: That is what I did @Barmar I used a url encode function within Objective C to get it into the format and then urldecode() in PHP.